# does Enable ASP.NET Session State in SharePoint (On SQL Server to persist session in database) Effect All web Applcations

Tags: sharepoint-server, session

When Enable `ASP.NET` Session State in SharePoint (On SQL Server to persist session in database) would add sessionstate entry in **all web applications** on farm

```
  <sessionState mode="SQLServer" timeout="60" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" 
  sqlConnectionString="Data Source=10.0.0.35;
  Initial Catalog=NewDataBaseName;Integrated Security=False;User ID= MyUserName;Password= MyPassword;
  Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15" />
```

Does it mean that all application Use Session Will save in database ? can i enable it for specific web application not all applications

Answer (score 1):

You can disable it per web application by modifying the web configuration file and setting

```
<page enableSessionState="false"...
```

And to enable it

```
<page enableSessionState="true"...
```

Comment: can i still use session but  session not save in database  if i set enableSessionState=false in this application application ? in anther meaning can i have two application in the same farm use session one save session in database and one in tradition way?

Comment: Yes.. so if you say false it will not use SessionState Service..

Comment: it's not work , I have Two Application using session to save value but i just need one application to save in database and the other application in memory this not happend event if nableSessionState="false" because enable session but models <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" />